# Passing data from client to wcf service to domain layer

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, design-patterns

I want a consumer app to send some data structure to a wcf service, then this service pass the data to the business model objects.

What I would like is to avoid the need to copy manually each property of the service data object to a new business object.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyServiceData
{
    [DataMember]
    public Property1() { get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Property2() { get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Property3() { get; set;}
}

public class MyWcfService : IMyWcfService 
{
    public void Operation1(MyServiceData data)
    {
        var obj = new DomainObject();
        obj.Property1 = data.Property1;
        obj.Property2 = data.Property2;
        obj.Property3 = data.Property3;

        obj.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I could put MyServiceData class in the business object layer, but I don't think it is a good thing to use these wcf service attributes in a business model object.

Is there any design pattern I could use to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried using a Mapper to move data between simple structs/models like that?

Comment: But with a mapper the copy would still happen right ? 
wouldn't it be a good idea to keep the same reference of the data object across layers ?
This would also avoid to modify the copying code every time a new property is added

Comment: That would happen, correct. But the Mapper makes it simpler (4 less lines of code in your example). You are correct that a pure domain model should not have WCF tags. If you want pure layers, then mapping somewhere is required.

Comment: If you aren't concerned with perfectly pure layers, then you could use your MyServiceData as the Domain object.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this issue is to use Adapter pattern like this. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Here is a sample implementation:

```
public class MyDomainObject
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyDomainObjectWcfAdapter
{
    private readonly MyDomainObject _object;

    public MyDomainObjectWcfAdapter(MyDomainObject obj)
    {
        this._object = obj;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return this._object.MyProperty; }
        set { this._object.MyProperty = value; }
    }

    public MyDomainObject GetObject()
    {
        return this._object;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems too complex when some property is also a custom type to copy from ws layer to business layer

Comment: Overall I agree with you. That is one of the inherent downsides of using a framework... you are bound by it's constraints. Sometimes that makes certain solution complex.  http://tomasp.net/blog/2015/library-frameworks/index.html